# can mysql concat only take two arguments

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to build a string using MySQL 5.5.15 but it seems to not work for more than two args:

```
mysql> select concat(id, name) as me from locations; # this works
mysql> select concat(id, name, website) as me from locations; # doesn't work
```

Some of the examples have > 2 args but it just doesn't seem to work. Should it work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try using `CONCAT_WS()`

```
SELECT CONCAT_WS('', id, name, website) AS me FROM locations
              -- ^ this is an empty char separator, 
              --   you can define what ever you want
```

- [MySQL CONCAT_WS()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_concat-ws)

This may be a wild guess but I think the value of column `website` is `NULL`. `CONCAT` may act differntly with `CONCAT_WS()` because it doesn't convert `NULL` values into default string.

Here's a simple DEMO: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c8d79/3

Comment: I think your second point is correct, dang.... would rather have it output something else. well thanks

Comment: @timpone is `website` `NULL`? because `CONCAT()` can take multiple numbers of arguments.

Comment: you can still use `COALESCE()` example, `select concat(id, name, COALESCE(website,'')) ....`